# crawl a static html site in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How do I crawl a static html site? Where in SharePoint do I upload html pages and how do I crawl it?

Comment: is it external html site or u created html pages and uploaded to sharepoint?

Comment: Let's say if there are html pages uploaded to a library in Sharepoint? Should I review each file for no-crawl tags or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

To crawl external htlm site, you dont need to upload it. You need to create a new content source and crawl the site.

- On Search admin page, click on Manage Content Source.
- On this Page click on New Content Source.
- Complete the farm click ok.
- Run the full crawl.
- Make sure you Search Content Account has Permission on external html site.

Read more over here: [Configure external site as content sources in sharepoint search](https://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/configure-external-site-as-content-sources-in-sharepoint-search/)