# Sharepoint Online doesn't crawl contents of htm files in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, html, crawl

29/10/2018 04/11/2018

Uploaded a bunch of htm files to a Sharepoint Server 2013 (on prem) library. Crawled the contents, confirmed in the log. I'm able to search the contents of it successfully.

Did the same to a library in Sharepoint Online. Even after a while I can't get the results of search from that content. Can't check the crawl logs so I'm not sure if Sharepoint Online is actually being able to crawl htm's contents.

At first I thought the files had some no-crawl header tag of sorts, but it did worked fine on on-prem crawl. Why would Sharepoint Online ignore it's contents?

Similar question here:

[crawl a static html site in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147931/crawl-a-static-html-site-in-sharepoint-2013/253497?noredirect=1#comment270729_253497)

Comment: how long you waited for it?

Comment: Two days. At first I thought it was just about waiting the time for crawl, but then I noticed newer contents coming on search results while those htm files are still not coming as results. At this point it's either a glitch (or an error on crawling) or search isn't supposed to crawl those htm files (and I don't know why.